# mysql - look at succeeding hours data from a certain hour and day of week

Tags: mysql

First of all, sorry for not being so clear.

Say I have a table gathering a certain NASDAQ stock value every 5 minutes. Now, I want to assert an assessment that every week on Monday at 9:00AM the stock is worth investing. How do I create a SQL statement that will look on each monday's data from 9AM and onwards (say, next  6 hours) and return the change in value 6 hours later, on same Monday at 15:00 so I can check that my assessment is True or False ?

Basically the SQL would return something like:

```
 
Date         Value at 9AM       Value at 15PM

Sep16-2013    $90                $92

Sep09-2013    $85                $88

Sep02-2013    $87                $91
```

.....

Comment: Could you show us your table's structure?

Comment: For simplicity, just assume the table has the following fields: datetime, value

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that uses correlated subqueries to get the values for those times.  In fact, it gets the first value recorded after that time on the same date:

```
select date(s.valuetime) as thedate,
       (select value
        from stocks s2
        where date(s.valuetime) = date(s2.valuetime) and
              hour(s.valuetime) >= 9 and
              s2.stock = s.stock
        order by s2.valuetime
        limit 1
       ) as `Value at 9am`,
       (select value
        from stocks s2
        where date(s.valuetime) = date(s2.valuetime) and
              hour(s.valuetime) >= 15 and
              s2.stock = s.stock
        order by s2.valuetime
        limit 1
       ) as `Value at 3pm`
from stocks s
group by date(s.valuetime) and dayofweek(s.valuetime) = 2;
```